# Xcode 8.1: UITests are NOT running

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Something very strange is happening with Xcode 8.1 UITests.
When I run any of my UI Tests, it builds fine, the simulator launches - it shows the screen as seen below, then the simulator just closes and nothing happens after that. No error message - nothing. Is there a simulator log where I can see what is going on?

[image]

I should mention this started to happen after I added a third party dynamic library.

Comment: This kind of thing happens with these tests sometimes. I'd recommend remove the test target and app from the simulator, clean the project and reinstall. If that doesn't work, try making a sample app and see if any UI tests run at all on your version of Xcode / simulator.